# Getting error while creating hitting /admin endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying be build an Token Authentication using DRF AuthToken. I want my own customisation for USER model, and this is how I have done. Now I want to login into Django Admin Panel, but when I hit that endpoint I get an error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'roadmap.tutor_authuser' doesn't exist")
```

and when I am trying to createsuperuser its asks for my email and after entering that I am getting same error.

This is how my custom USER Model is,

```
class AuthUser(AbstractUser):
    ADMIN = 'A'
    STUDENT = 'S'
    TUTOR = 'T'
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, 'Superuser'),
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
        (TUTOR, 'Tutor'),
    )
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=STUDENT)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

I also have done make migration and migrate successfully. And this is how my migration file looks like

```
# Generated by Django 4.1 on 2022-08-09 04:40

import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Roadmap',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('course_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('course_title', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('course_description', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Section',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('section_title', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('section_description', models.TextField()),
                ('roadmap', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='tutor.roadmap')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SubSection',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('subsection_title', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('subsection_description', models.TextField()),
                ('section', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='tutor.section')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)),
                ('role', models.CharField(choices=[('A', 'Superuser'), ('S', 'Student'), ('T', 'Tutor')], default='S', max_length=1)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Maybe some problem with migration files, have you deleted any of them?

Comment: I deleted all the migration file, and then done that make migrations and migrate thing again. Here the ss of it https://ibb.co/xH0GHSD. Have a look at it. The issue persist.

Comment: Have you also deleted the db sqlite file at that time?

Comment: I am using MySQL in db. And no I haven't touched the MySQL db at all.

Comment: You should delete that MySQL database and migration files, then create new db and run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Yo, done that, and it successfully done. But when creating superuser I am getting an error **TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'**, though I have explicitly mentioned username = none. Now when I type createsuperuser, it prompt to ask for email and password, after entering the password, above error prompt up. I am worried about one thing that there is no column have provided for password(though I want), and it still asking me for password

Answer (score 0):

if you are learning django with this project and you are not developing a production, you can delete your db file and migrating again to create new db file

Comment: I deleted all the migration file, and then done that make migrations and migrate thing again. Here the ss of it https://ibb.co/xH0GHSD. Have a look at it

Comment: migrate your app, not full project:
`python3 manage.py migrate <appname>`. you need to first migrate your custom user model, then migrate django default apps

Comment: Done that. This is how my model looks like [Link](http://pastebin.com/uLSq4ny2). Now when creating superuser I am getting the following error **TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'** Exact error prompt [Link](http://ibb.co/2ZGsFhf). Just in case if you wanna look at mine migration file here it is:- [Link](http://pastebin.com/jRdSmW7L)

Comment: this error is happening because you set username to None in your CustomUserModel. Note that if you inherit from AbstractUser in your CustomUserModel, you do not need to define the username attribute